# Retaining keypoints in GPU memory for efficient pipelining

Tags: opencv, orb

Is it possible using the CUDA API for openCV to retain keypoints and descriptors returned from a feature detector and descriptor (orb->detectAndCompute) in GPU memory so that we can pass the keypoints and descriptors straight to a knnMatch, without having to download and re-upload the keypoints and descriptors? It will avoid inefficient memory transfers in a pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizing the asynchronous set of functions from the CUDA API, this exact result can be achieved. The [following](https://github.com/gerrywalsh/CppMT) repository does just in it's implementation of feature extraction, description and matching to a database.